# selectize.js remote fills other input

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps

I have a selectized input `#location` where a user enters his location and it displays dropdown choices from the [google geocoding api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro?hl=en_US).

It works well, but now what I'd like is to fill another input `#latitude` when the user selects one of the suggested location.

I'm partly able to do it using this code :

```
$('#location').selectize({
        valueField: 'formatted_address',
        labelField: 'formatted_address',
        searchField: 'formatted_address',
        maxItems: 1,
        delimiter: ';',
        create: false,
        load: function (query, callback) {
            if (!query.length) return callback();
            $.ajax({
                url: "googleloc",
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    search: query,
                },
                error: function () {
                    callback();
                },
                success: function (res) {
                    callback(res.results);
                }
            });
        }

    });

    $('#location').on('change', function () {
        var test = $('#location').selectize()[0].selectize.getValue();
        $('#latitude').val(test);
    });
```

My issue is that this piece of code fills the `#latitude` input with the `'formatted_address'` but not with the latitude, which as you can see in the json below returned by the load option is under geometry > location > lat.

A sample of the json returned is here :

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "French Polynesia",
               "short_name" : "PF",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "French Polynesia",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : -7.8955619,
                  "lng" : -138.6091323
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : -23.9062409,
                  "lng" : -153.9919066
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -17.679742,
               "lng" : -149.406843
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : -17.4943169,
                  "lng" : -149.1247993
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : -17.8803223,
                  "lng" : -149.6211207
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJTddtfNB1GHQREVfDCXp6wJs",
         "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

edit : a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4wsrf6rd/5/) with the github api, I'm at a loss creating one with the google map api as you need a key which I'd prefer not to share :)

Comment: simplier could be parsing your Google API response to javascript object with JSON.parse() and access the field you really want from this object.

Comment: If you have solved your problem, please provide an answer and [accept it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), rather than editing the solution into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it done thanks to @Comte comment, here is the solution

```
$('#location').selectize({
        valueField: 'formatted_address',
        labelField: 'formatted_address',
        searchField: 'formatted_address',
        maxItems: 1,
        delimiter: ';',
        create: false,
        load: function (query, callback) {
            if (!query.length) return callback();
            $.ajax({
                url: "googleloc",
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    search: query,
                },
                error: function () {
                    callback();
                },
                success: function (res) {
                    callback(res.results);
                    googresults = res.results;
                }
            });
        },
        onChange: function (value) {
            if (!value.length) return;
            for (var key in googresults) {
                if (googresults[key].formatted_address == value) {
                    var lat = googresults[key].geometry.location.lat;
                    var lng = googresults[key].geometry.location.lng;
                }

            }
            $('#latitude').val(lat);
            $('#longitude').val(lng);
        }

    });
```